# tsWhat's the probability that, if picked 2 real numbers from the interval $[{-25, 15}]$, the product of those real numbers are negative?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

I came across this question while revisiting old Antalya Math Olympiad questions. Specifically, this one's from the 2012 Contest. I don't get how I'm supposed to quantify the sample space, since there are infinitely many <s>combinations</s> numbers to choose from. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't use the word *combination* when dealing with continuous variables e.g. the *real* variables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, drawn from the interval $[-25, 15]$. Each of the variables can either be positive or negative, and most importantly the product is negative iff one is positive and one is negative. There are two such cases:

1. If $X_1$ is positive and $X_2$ is negative. The probability of this happening is $\frac{15}{40}\cdot\frac{25}{40}$.
2. If $X_2$ is positive and $X_1$ is negative, by symmetry the probability is also $\frac{15}{40}\cdot\frac{25}{40}$.

Therefore, the total probability that their product is negative is $P(X_1X_2 < 0) = 2\cdot\frac{15}{40}\cdot\frac{25}{40} = \frac{15}{32}$.